# Google contacts api on android

Tags: java, android, google-contacts-api

I've been at this for days and im getting confused.

I've read in many places that the java client google provides "wont work on android", and it doesn't.

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ContactsService service = new ContactsService("my_app_name");


    URL feedUrl = null;
    try {
        feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        service.setUserCredentials("anAccount@gmail.com", "thePassword");

        ContactFeed resultFeed = new ContactFeed();

        resultFeed = service
                .getFeed(feedUrl, ContactFeed.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And i get:

```
W/XmlParser(793): javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities
```

Comment: @norbert Did you have any solution for this? Can you please share me your code or links?

Comment: I have solved the problem with GData api. See this post(http://noundla.blogspot.in/2014/01/fetch-googlegmail-contacts-using-google.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a newer Google APIs Java Client library that DOES work on Android, and it's at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/.

I have personally used this with the Google Documents List API (however, it did require creating XML model classes as per http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Google_Data_APIs).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the contacts of the user of the phone why not try the [Contacts content provider](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html)?

Comment: this link is now dead.

Comment: Inappropriate answer. Read the question carefully before do answer.